# Difference Between Service.create approaches

Tags: java, web-services, service, wsdl

I'm using a third party library that wraps a SOAP Service.

It uses the following idiom

```
String url = SOME_URL
QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("http://www.example.com/Webapp/1", "WS")
QName PORT_NAME = new QName("http://www.example.com/Webapp/1", "WSPort")
Service service = Service.create(SERVICE_NAME)
service.addPort(PORT_NAME, "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/http", url)
SomeWebService port = service.getPort(SomeWebService.class)
```

This does not work I get the following error

```
WSDL Metadata not available to create the proxy, either Service instance or ServiceEndpointInterface
```

If, however, I change the idiom slightly to use the URL in the Service creation

```
String url = SOME_URL
QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("http://www.example.com/Webapp/1", "WS")
QName PORT_NAME = new QName("http://www.example.com/Webapp/1", "WSPort")
Service service = Service.create(new URL(url), SERVICE_NAME)
SomeWebService port = service.getPort(SomeWebService.class)
```

Then it works fine. Unfortunately this is a third party jar and I only know this due to decompilation. Is it possible that I have a bad version of one of the dependent jars? Other people seem to have had the same problem but they were able to make the above change. I am not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that this issue is caused by the fact that the third party jar I am using was written against Java 1.5 which did not contain its own versions of CXF, JAXB, etc. overriding these versions in my pom file to use the ones that would have been available with Java 1.5 solved the problem.